# electron ready-to-show weird issue

Tags: javascript, electron

When I use the `trackwin.once('ready-to-show')` function, I check if `config.tracking` is **true**. If it is, I try to show the window. Otherwise, I close it. Then, I send the track contents to my HTML file. In the HTML file, I handle the rest using JavaScript. The problem is that sometimes the window shows up as expected, especially the first time, but most of the time, it closes instantly. The issue is the else statement gets executed instead of the true statement so it executes `trackwin.hide()` instead of `trackwin.show()` as intended.

```
trackwin.once('ready-to-show', () => {
      try {
            if (config.tracking == "true") {
                trackwin.show()
            } else {
                trackwin.hide()
            }
        } catch {
            trackwin.show()
        }

        trackwin.webContents.send('track', game, placeid)
    })
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you don't "close" the window, you merely hide it. Also, your `config.tracking` value should probably be a boolean (read about the fine details of `==` in JavaScript). Furthermore, how do you set `config.tracking`? Is there a possibility for a race condition (sounds like it)? Please [edit] your question to contain the relevant parts also.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a asynchronous issue. I just changed it to this `trackwin.once('ready-to-show', async () => {})` and delcared the config.json inside the function.